# truncated output parameter from executenonquery

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to implement ExecuteNonQuery in C#. 
The storedProcedure on its own is working fine when I execute in SQL. It is returning a GUID for SubmissionId and the text 'submit sequence' for SubmitSequence. But in .net, it's returning one character as output for SubmitSequence

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[test_SP]
(
    @FormId uniqueidentifier,
    @FormCode varchar(10),
    @FormTitle nvarchar(200),
    @User nvarchar(50),
    @Url nvarchar(255) = NULL,
    @Host nvarchar(50),
    @RemoteHost nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @UserAgent nvarchar(255) = NULL, 
    @Referrer nvarchar(255) = NULL,
    @SubmissionId uniqueidentifier out,
    @SubmitSequence varchar(30) out
) AS

BEGIN 

SET @SubmissionId = newid();
set @SubmitSequence = 'submit sequence'

-- INSERT Query
SELECT 
    @SubmissionId as SubmissionId,  @SubmitSequence  as SubmitSequence
END
```

But in the .net, I am getting the GUID for SubmissionId(which is correct) and the text 's' for SubmitSequence.

```
public SubmissionHeaderDTO GetRefNo()
        {
            var inPrms = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                            {
                                {"FormId", Guid.NewGuid()},
                                {"FormCode", "TST"},
                                {"FormTitle", "Test form"},
                                {"User", "test"},
                                {"Host", "iisserver"}                               
                            };
            var outPrms = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) { 
                            { "SubmissionId", Guid.NewGuid() },
                            { "SubmitSequence", "two"}
                            };
            var result = DBHelper.ExecSP(Constants.SPNames.SubmissionHeaderInsert, inPrms, outPrms);
            SubmissionHeaderDTO refNo = DictionaryToObject<SubmissionHeaderDTO>(result);
            return refNo;
        }
```

DBHelper.cs

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> ExecSP(string sp, Dictionary<string, object> paramIn, Dictionary<string, object> paramOut)
        {
            var dbAccess = new DBAccess();
            var results = dbAccess.ExecuteQuery(sp, paramIn, paramOut);
            return results;
        }
```

DBAccess.cs

```
public class DBAccess
    {
        public Dictionary<string, object> ExecuteQuery(string storedProcedure, Dictionary<string, object> parameters,
                                          Dictionary<string, object> outParameters)
        {

            using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.DBConnection))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                using(var transaction = sqlConn.BeginTransaction("Results"))
                {
                    using(var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, sqlConn, transaction))
                    {
                        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        foreach(var kv in parameters)
                        {
                            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kv.Key, kv.Value);
                        }
                        foreach(var kv in outParameters)
                        {
                            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kv.Key, kv.Value).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            var result = GetOutputParameters(sqlcmd.Parameters);
                            transaction.Commit();
                            return result;
                        }
                        catch(Exception)
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private Dictionary<string, object> GetOutputParameters(SqlParameterCollection paramCollection)
        {
            var returnParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (SqlParameter par in paramCollection)
            {
                if ((par.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output) || (par.Direction == ParameterDirection.ReturnValue))
                {
                    returnParameters.Add(par.ParameterName, par.Value);
                }
            }
            return returnParameters;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Output params are not supposed to be part of the procedure's result set - you should not be `SELECT`ing them. Keep the `SET` statements but remove the `SELECT` statement and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: No, it didn't make any difference. I have just left the SET statements. The output parameter value for Submission Sequence is just the first character.

Answer (score 1):

I put your code into my own solution and recreated the problem. You are running into one of the reasons you should actually never do `AddWithValue`. Since you are adding a generic `object`, there is no way to infer what data type the sql parameter should be. If you break before `ExecuteNonQuery` and inspect the parameter list you will see it is defined as `NVARCHAR` with no length. So by default it is length 1.
You need to build your sql parameters with a real `SqlDbType` and you should set them with the `Value` property instead of `AddWithValue`.

> UPDATE

To get started dynamically querying the parameter meta-data look at this. Note you still have more work to do, like mapping the sql types to `SqlDbType`:

```
DECLARE @spName sysname;
SET @spName = 'test_SP';

DECLARE @objId int;
SELECT @objId = ISNULL([object_id], 0) FROM sys.procedures WHERE [name] = @spName;

SELECT p.[name], p.[system_type_id], t.[name], p.[max_length], p.[precision], 
    p.[scale], p.[is_output], p.[is_nullable]
FROM sys.parameters p
INNER JOIN sys.systypes t
    ON p.[system_type_id] = t.[xtype]
WHERE [object_id] = @objId;
```

[image]

Comment: I have to use a generic object in my case. Could you please suggest how can I use 'Add' with SqlDbType and length in my case without using AddWithValue

Comment: You could query the `sys.parameters` view to figure out the parameter metadata for a stored procedure at runtime.

Comment: It is returning all the output parameters except for NVarchar. Could anyone please write a linq to extract the parameters of sqldbtype = nvarchar and parameterdirection = output and set the size of that parameter to 100. That will solve my purpose

Comment: If it is not returning all the expected parameters then your stored procedure isn't built the way you think it is. `sys.parameters` doesn't return some of the parameters, it has them all.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to give the correct SQLDbType and Size to your parameter. Especially if you omit the Size, your output will be truncated to 1 character.

SQL:

```
    @szError nvachar(max) output
```

C#:

```
    SqlParameter szError = new SqlParameter("szError", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    {
      Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
      Size = 4000
    };
```